# pyspark split data frame into few data frames by column

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working with Python (pyspark)

I have a dataframe which contains data for a few users

```
IMSI   X        Y

1      139620   179284

1      139620   179284

3      138620   178284

3      138620   178284

3      138620   178284
```

I want to create RDD-DF object that split by IMSI column

so that I will be able to operate a Python function for each DF

```
SplitDF.map(PythonFunctionForEachUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can use. If you want to operate on RDD you can use `groupByKey`:

```
df.rdd.keyBy(lambda r: r.IMSI).groupByKey().map(lambda a: PythonFunctionForEachUser(a[1]))
```

If you prefer Dataframes, you can group by IMSI column and then `collect_list`, but first you need to merge these x and y into one column:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import array
>>> df.withColumn('data', array('x', 'y')).groupBy('IMSI') \
         .agg(collect_list('data').alias('userdata')) \
         .rdd.map(PythonFunctionForEachUser)
```